# Are there any cons when using view binding rather than findViewById?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-viewbinding

Since I discovered the use of view binding by enabling

```
   buildFeatures {
         viewBinding true
     }
```

in my gradle file, I never used findviewById in my code again. I wonder now if there is a cons to doing things this way.
If this is the best method, why does android studio not enable this option by default when creating a new project? If not, when should I avoid using view binding? thank you.

Comment: read it [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#findviewbyid)

Comment: Thank you but i think this link is  talking about viewbinding and data binding. this not exactly what want here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you enable it for a project, view binding will generate a binding class for all of your layouts. That's the only "con" I see, it just generates more code, so it would increase the size of the project, compile time, etc. While it won't be a huge difference for projects with very little layouts, it could change significantly for larger projects.

Here's a very interesting read about ViewBinding performance : https://blog.stylingandroid.com/view-binding-performance/

Comment: Thank you @Praveen. can you please tell me why do you think the generation of binding classes is an inconvenient?

Comment: Because it can increase the size of the project, therefore, the build time. It probably won't be noticeable in small projects, but it can make a difference in a larger project with loads of layouts. Although the benefits of ViewBinding may significantly outweigh the small build time hit. I was just mentioning it because you asked for a con, and this is the only con I could think of ;)

Comment: This is NOT TRUE, you can easily exclude a layout from being generated by adding tools:viewBindingIgnore=“false” to the root

Comment: well, yes, of course, but then you're not using ViewBinding. He was asking about the cons of using it. Also, having to add that to every layout that you don't want to generate a binding class is quite some work

Comment: I said `you can easily exclude a layout` if you don't want to create ViewBinding class for that layout, not `all`.
Its completely a developer's choice. In that specific case, your CON is not actually right.

Comment: That link doesn't mention anything about performance

Comment: you're right, sorry about the wrong link: this is the one I was meant to post

https://blog.stylingandroid.com/view-binding-performance/